# Oracle APEX: Execute immediate on collection

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, execute

I have the following code:

```
declare
    y pls_integer := 0;
    v_msg varchar2(4000);
    plsql varchar(4000);
begin
    if not apex_collection.collection_exists(p_collection_name=>'P16_COLLECTION') then
        wwv_flow.debug('No Apex collection found!');
    else
        for x in (select * from apex_collections where collection_name = 'P16_COLLECTION' and seq_id > 1 order by seq_id) 
        loop
           y := y+1;
           FOR i IN 1..25
           LOOP
               plsql := 'begin apex_collection.update_member_attribute (p_collection_name=> ''P16_COLLECTION'', p_seq=>' || TO_CHAR(x.seq_id) || ',p_attr_number =>' || TO_CHAR(i) || ',p_attr_value=>wwv_flow.g_f' || TO_CHAR(i, 'FM00') || '(' || TO_CHAR(y) || ')); end;';
               wwv_flow.debug(plsql);
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql;
           END LOOP;
        end loop;   
    end if;
exception when others then
    v_msg := ''||sqlerrm;
    wwv_flow.debug('ERR: '||v_msg);
end;
```

This code is very similar to the one proposed [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-nov/o66browser-100525.html), but I loop through 25 columns. The issue with Oracle Apex is the max number of chars PL/SQL is allowed to have, so I am unable to just write 25 `update_member_attribute` - calls.

But instead of a it excecuting I get an error `no data found`.

I triple checked that the collection `P16_COLLECTION` exists.

Comment: I suggest that since you don't need dynamic SQL to call `apex_collection.update_member_attribute`, you should avoid it. Instead, minimise the dynamic SQL to the minimum necessary to get the `wwv_flow.g_fnn(y)` values. Even better, unroll the loop and use static PL/SQL all the way.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue with Oracle Apex is the max number of chars PL/SQL is allowed to have

I'm not sure I understood this statement. It is PL/SQL you use. You declared a local PLSQL variable as VARCHAR2(4000). Why didn't you specify its max allowed size, 32767? Would that help?

Furthermore, saying that you got NO-DATA-FOUND exception: are you **sure** that this piece of code raised it? Because, there's no SELECT statement in there ... the one you used in a cursor FOR loop can't raise NO-DATA-FOUND; UPDATE either. Therefore, it must be something else, I presume.

Enable DEBUG, run the page and - when you get the error - view debug results and locate the culprit.

Comment: I was not talking about the variable, I was talking about the code itself. APEX will raise an error when the code is too long.

Comment: Aha; I think I understand now what you're saying. Which Apex version do you use? Up to 4.2 (maybe) or 5.0 (for sure), Apex tables that store code we write was VARCHAR2(4000) so any code longer than that was "invalid". Maybe you hit that restrictions? In recent Apex versions it is CLOB (I think) so you can write a very, very long query, and it'll work. So, if you're on a lower version, see whether you can move that code into a stored procedure and call it from Apex. If not, huh, no idea ...